# reflection type checking?

Tags: java, reflection, types

I'd like to find a way to dynamically check if string is parse-able into a given type.
in other words,

```
public boolean canBeParsed(String type, String val) {
    // use reflect to check if val can be parsed into type
}
```

clearly, I'd like to be able check different types with different values..

types will be strings like : Java.lang.Integer

---------- addition -------------

so for example, if I call this function,

```
canBeParsed("Java.lang.Integer", "1"); //returns true

canBeParsed("Java.lang.Integer", "HelloWorld"); //returns false

canBeParsed("Java.lang.String", "HelloWorld"); //returns true

canBeParsed("Java.lang.Boolean", "false"); // returns true

canBeParsed("Java.lang.Boolean", "HelloWorld"); //returns false
```

Comment: Can you give a better example? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: is this homework? if so, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method works with classes which declare a static valueOf method. Any class without this will return false. Several exceptions have been omitted to keep the code short.

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(type);
//Get a converter method, String to  type
//Requires static method valueOf
Method converter;
try{
converter = cls.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf",new Class[]{String.class});
}catch(NoSuchMethodError ex){
   //No conversion method found
   return false;
}
if(!Modifier.isStatic(converter.getModifiers()){
   //the method has to be static in order to be called by us
   return false;
}
if(!cls.isAssignableFrom(converter.getReturnType())
    //The conversion method has the wrong return type
    return false;
try{
    //try to parse the value
    Object o = converter.invoke(null,new Object[]{value};
    if( o == null)return false;//false if method returned null
    else return true;//success
}catch(Exception ex)
{
    //could not parse value
    return false;
}
```

The valueOf(String) method is present in the wrapper classes Short,Long,Integer,Float,Double,Boolean so it supports these and any other class which has this method.

Comment: thanks ! worked great. of course, had to put the obvious case: "if (type.equals("java.lang.String")) return true;" for people that may find this code useful ..

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic type check is something different from what you are asking. With a dynamic check you check if an obect *is an* instance of a specific type (basically sametype or narrower type will be allowed) and you can do it with the `instanceof` operator. But this involves the object hierarchy and not the "can be converted to" concept that you would like to have. You can try with `string instanceof Integer` but this will be ALWAYS false.

In your situation you want to check if a string rapresents an integer number and you should do it in a different way:

```
try {
  int number = Integer.parseInt(string);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  System.out.println("String is not an integer string!");
}
```

Otherwise you could define a regex for every type and check what the string contains through it:

```
if (string.matches("[1-9][0-9]*"))
  ...
```

In anycase, since a `String` is just a string type and nothing else, the RTTI won't help you here. The string itself is orthogonal with every other type (int, float, whatever) also if it rapresents the textual version of another type.

A solution can be found if you can modify the source string types, in this case you could define for example an

```
class IntString extends String {
  IntString(int i) {
     super(Integer.toString(i));
  }
}
```

then you could check if `string instanceof IntString` but this would work only if the strings are built with their specific type eg `String s = new IntString(20)`.

Comment: Should be `Integer.parseInt()` (static method).

Comment: function i wanted was one that not only limited to Integer parsing, but many other types. in other words, as parameter, i may have Java.lang.String, Java.lang.Integer, Java.lang.Float, Java.lang.Boolean and so on

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest solution is probably a `switch` statement, with one `case` for each type that you want to support.

```
public boolean canBeParsed(String type, String val)
{
     switch(type) {
         case "Java.lang.Integer" : return(tryParseInteger(val) != null);
         case ...
}


public static Integer tryParseInteger(String text) {
  try {
    return new Integer(text);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

In C# this would be easier, as there is an actual TryParse() method for each numeric type, and it's not necessary to catch an exception to test it.